# How to insert External html code to Div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Html code,index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">

            <div class="menu_div">
                <ul id="menu-bar">
                    <div id="menu_div">
                        <li><a href="#" id="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#men">Men</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#women">Women</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#cosmetics">Cosmetics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="control">
            <p style="position:relative;">Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>  

</body>
```

Here is my Jquery code,to change external div

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#aboutus').click(function () {           
                $('#control').load('AboutUs.html #controlAboutUs') ;
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

and Here is my External Html.AboutUs.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>About us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="controlAboutUs">
        <div>
            <h3>Welcome From Ivory's Collection</h3>
            <p>
                We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.We export Clothes,Accessories and Branded cosmetics from Japan Directly. We are fully guranteed for quality and designs.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with simple code for that, it worked. But in this files, it is not working. I don't know why... pls help me

Comment: Did you get any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: why it is not working? any error?

Comment: nope, no error.I create another file like this and I run, I worked.But In that index.html, it's not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh buddy, don't use hash when declaring an id on your html code.

e.g.

```
 <li><a href="#" id="aboutus">About Us</a></li>
```

That should do it.